# Local storage and Internet Explorer 9 adventures

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, local-storage

I have interesting issue in Internet Explorer 9 using localStorage. I use client-side localization in my web project using `i18next` library and as a localization storage we decided to use localStorage. We are loading all localization at the user first visit(whole localization for one language ~ 450kb). All is working well in all browser, except Internet explorer 9. After some time and switching between languages I start receiving error - `"SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR (22)"`, when it trying to load localization from server-side. When I try - `localStorage.remainingSpace` it returns: `120776`

However when i try to look what is stored in localStorage with a command -  `JSON.stringify(localStorage)` it returns - `"{}"`. So nothing is stored in localStorage however it writes that only 120kb is free. When I try on any other web site, for the command - `localStorage.remainingSpace` it shows - `5000000`. Also `localStorage.clear()` is not helping to stop receiving that message - `"SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR (22)"`

The question is - 'Why internet explorer 9 thinks that localStorage is almost full while it don't contain any data?'

Thanks for any advance.

Comment: The obvious answer is: Because you found an Internet Explorer bug that Microsoft needs to fix. So if this issue is still reproducible in more recent versions you should report it. On the other hand, if it is already fixed in IE10 then you should be happy and simply give up on IE9.

Comment: what does localStorage.length report?

Comment: localStorage.length=>0

Comment: the quota is per origin, so maybe you have other subdomains?

Comment: Out of curiosity, since you say the problem only occurs after switching between languages, what happens when you switch a language? Do you override the current localstorage key for the localization? Do you add a new entry into localstorage? Does the server-side append each new localization to the request (making it bigger every time)?

Comment: When I switch between the languaguages i clear whole localStorage(with `localStorage.clear()`) and fetch the data from server-side once more. No I use the localization language alias as a localStorage key(en-US, ru-RU, etc). Client don't fetch localization from server-side until you change the language.

Comment: About subdomains, no whole application runs on single domain.

Comment: What's on sessionStorage? Maybe there is something in there, maybe IE9 is sharing the quota between localStorage & sessionStorage.

Comment: sessionStorage is also empty. sessionStorage.length = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

know how frustrating IE can be. I ran into a similar issue.

Try this [this jquery plugin](http://www.jstorage.info/#support). Also see if [this](https://github.com/andris9/jStorage/issues/8) IE9 issue matches your use case
The plugin itself tries various fallbacks short of setting an actual cookie. They integrate several persistence mechanisms in a seamless API regardless of browser, as long as it's on their supported list, it'll work, within the size limitation.

[If 450kb does not fit, try to create a server-backed fallback that actively fetches required keys that are missing from the local storage so that you do not transfer the entire 450k dictionary.]

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help. But that plugin is also using localStorage on a low level, so the same problem will appear. Also your workaround will work, BUT the localStorage I'm using to decreas the count of request to server. So that workaround will just break the idea of localStorage usage.